# С предлогом или без?

Tags: грамотная-речь, предлоги

Как правильно задать вопрос в ответ на реплику:

> Я ещё до мужчины пришла.

Только *"до какого мужчины?"* или можно также опустить предлог и спросить *"какого мужчины"*?

Раньше, когда опускал предлог, невольно казалось, что ошибаюсь и надо поправиться. А может, не надо?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я думаю, в разговорной речи предлог вполне можно опустить. Сомнений в смысле не вызывает.
Пример, конечно, у вас не самый актуальный сам по себе. Без контекста и не сразу поймешь, о чем речь, вон Ниманд привычно принял за суржик...

Но давайте разберемся. А если обратная ситуация: "Я уже после мужчины пришла" - будете ли вы повторять это "после" в вопросе "Какого мужчины?", а? Не думаю... 
В сугубо литературной речи, конечно, опускать предлог не стоит - об этом уже много раз говорили, не буду повторяться.
А в разговоре... Ну нет же жесткого требования повторения предлога, даже в предложном падеже возможно "ехал на автобусе и троллейбусе". - Да, тут-то аналогичный вопрос *"Каком троллейбусе?"* будет смотреться диковато, но у нас-то явно не предложный падеж.
*Было бы где и на кого сослаться - сослался бы. Но пока - чем могу, личное мнение.*

Comment: Спасибо большое, behemothus! Рад вашему возвращению!! Сравнение с "после" интересно и показательно. Действительно, вряд ли это "после" станешь повторять. А раз так, то и с "до" должно быть аналогично. Интересен и пример с троллейбусом. Действительно, звучит не очень, хотя что-то мне подсказывает, что по аналогии с тем примером мог бы и в этом пропустить предлог. Но согласен, что интуитивно в этом падеже хуже звучит. Буду ориентироваться просто на ваше мнение, хотя бы без аргументации, почему возникает разница в разных падежах.

Comment: А пример я непосредственно взял из жизни, то есть тот, который заставил меня задуматься об этом. Думал сначала изменить пол, потом думаю: да ладно, спрошу, как было. На почте после женщины, за которой я занимал, прошла девушка и на мой вопрос, почему она прошла, ответила это. [Хотя я никакого мужчины и не запомнил. Но ответил "а-а, ясно", хотя на самом деле ничего не понял, но, думаю, ладно, не важно, подожду.)))] Простите за такие подробности.

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой *Рад вашему возвращению!!* - спасибо, да я, собственно, никуда и не уходил, просто отошел немного от дел, "покоя сердце просит",. В отношении "пример из жизни" - ну тут мне-то это было понятно, но контекст не настолько жизненный, чтобы его брать за основу. Все вполне можно изучить на чем-то более естественном, чем лукавая барышня,обманувшая очередь.

Comment: *хотя что-то мне подсказывает, что по аналогии с тем примером мог бы и в этом пропустить предлог* - вот тут постарайтесь поработать над собой. В современном русском "беспредложный предложный" - нонсенс даже в разговорной речи. Предлог невозможно отцепить"  от падежной формы, настолько, что тут впрору говорить о трех (или даже пяти) разных падежах - отвечающих на разные вопросы: "на чем?", "в чем?" и "о чем". Ну, может, до єтого дело и не дойдет, но факт что предлоги не только не отцепляемі, но и не взаимозаменяемі ни при каких обстоятельствах.

Comment: Ясно насчёт предлогов в предложном. Да, надо поработать, спасибо. Понравилась "лукавая барышня, обманувшая очередь". :))

Comment: Я теперь понял, в каком случае я мог бы пропустить предлог (в "На каком троллейбусе?"). В обычном случае я его бы уверенно произнёс, а пропустить могу, если чем-то смущён и разговариваю неуверенно, чего-то стесняюсь. Тогда у меня и дикция нарушается, произношу всё невнятно. Понял, что над этим тоже надо работать, то есть бороться с этим. Добиться, чтобы этого никогда не возникало или только в исключительных случаях.